# Easy way to bind rect to geometrical 2D line?

Tags: manipulate, geometry, geometric-transform

I got stuck with the following problem. For some calculation and visualization purposes I need to draw different shapes (like rectangle) with proper slope on custom line. The trivial example:

```
line = Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}];
hw = 0.01; (* half-width *)
hh = 0.05; (* half-height *)
Manipulate[Graphics[{line, Rectangle[{l - hw, hh}, {l + hw, -hh}]}], {l, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

But it becomes much more difficult in case of custom-shaped figures, say like:

```
l1 = Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}]; 
cir = Circle[{1, 0}, 1, {-\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}];
l2 = Line[{{0, -1}, {1, -1}}];
geom = {l1, cir, l2};

Graphics[geom]
```

[image]

Sure, there's always a straightforward way when you calculate slope and position manually, but it's time-consuming and so sombre. Is there any easier or 'automatic' way of solving such kind of tasks?

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify: you want the rectangle to move around your arc, such that the line through its center that is parallel to its longer sides is always normal to your arc?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. yes, precisely what I want.

Comment: Why not create the graphics, and then `Rotate`?

Comment: @yohbs right, but then you have to calculate manually local curvature in each point. It's ok when you draw functions in plot (simply derivative), but when you deal with arbitrary objects you need to recalculate it manually.. I just wonder is there in Mathematica some simpler approach

Comment: I think it would be easier if you'd give a specific problem that you're trying to solve. I don't quite understand the general problem that you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Motivation

In Mathematica most curves are ultimately rendered using `Line`, which has a straightforward derivative. Therefore it makes sense to create a function that solves the problem for the particular case of a `Line` object. For example

```
pts = Flatten[Cases[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity], 1];
```

is the list of points which make up the `Line` object that represents the `Sin` curve. So in order to draw the normal of the `Sin` curve you don't need to take the derivative of `Sin`, and the same goes for any other curve you can create with `Plot`, `ParametricPlot` etc.

### Solution

```
markerFunction[pts_] := 
 Module[{bspline, angInterp, marker, hw = 0.01, hh = 0.1},
  bspline = BSplineFunction[MovingAverage[pts, 2], SplineDegree -> 1];
  angInterp = Interpolation[ArcTan @@@ Differences@pts];
  marker[pt_, angle_] := Rotate[Translate[Rectangle[{-hw, hh}, {hw, -hh}], pt], angle];

  Function[t, Quiet@Graphics@marker[bspline[t], angInterp[Length[pts] t]]]
  ]
```

### Example

This example is a bit contrived since in this case the curve is not generated by for example `Plot` so we don't actually have a `Line` representation for it. But even so, all taken together, it is still a concise solution to the problem.

```
pts = AnglePath@Join[
    ConstantArray[{1/100, 0}, 100],
    ConstantArray[{1/100, Pi/100}, 100],
    ConstantArray[{1/100, 0}, 100]
    ];

markerf = markerFunction[pts];

Manipulate[
 Show[
  Graphics@Line@pts,
  markerf[t],
  PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.5}, {-0.5, 1}},
  AspectRatio -> Automatic
  ], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

With your figure

```
l1 = Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}];
cir = Circle[{1, 0}, 1, {-π/2, π]/2}];
l2 = Line[{{0, -1}, {1, -1}}];
geom = {l1, cir, l2};
g = Graphics[geom];
```

and the rectangle marker

```
l = 0; hw = 0.01; hh = 0.05;
marker = Rasterize@Magnify[Graphics@Rectangle[{l - hw, hh}, {l + hw, -hh}], 0.07]
```

one can create a binary image from the figure

```
bg = Binarize@g;
```

and for nicer visualization a rasterized version

```
rg = Rasterize@g;
```

The position of the pixels that are corresponding to the black line of the figure can be found with

```
pos = PixelValuePositions[bg, 0];
```

In the following `Manipulate` the position and angle of the marker gets specified by just three pixel positions

```
Manipulate[vectors = (# - p & /@ Nearest[pos, p, 37][[2 ;;]]);
 directionV = Subtract @@ Reverse@SortBy[vectors[[{-2, -1}]], Last]; 
 If[Norm[directionV] == 1, 
  directionV = Subtract @@ Reverse@SortBy[vectors[[{-3, -1}]], Last]];
 angles = VectorAngle[directionV, {1, 0}];
 Pane[rg, FrameMargins -> {{15, 15}, {15, 15}}],
 {angles, None}, {vectors, None}, {directionV, None}, {{p, pos[[1]]}, 
  Locator, TrackingFunction -> (p = Nearest[pos, #][[1]]; &), 
  Appearance -> Rotate[marker, angles]}, TrackedSymbols :> {p}]
```

[image: GIF]

Using a `Manipulator` to control the position and multiple points to determine the rectangle rotation:

```
posT = pos[[FindShortestTour[pos][[-1, ;; -2]]]];
Manipulate[
 angle = Median[
   VectorAngle[#, {1, 0}] & /@ (DeleteCases[
       Subtract @@ Reverse@SortBy[#, Last] & /@ 
        Partition[Nearest[pos, posT[[p]], 37][[2 ;;]], 2, 1],
         _?(Norm[#] == 1 &)] /. {} -> {{1, 0}})];
 LocatorPane[posT[[p]], rg, Appearance -> Rotate[marker, angle], 
  FrameMargins -> {{15, 15}, {15, 15}}, Background -> White],
 {angle, None}, {p, 1, Length@posT, 1}, TrackedSymbols :> {p}, 
 Deployed -> True]
```

[image: GIF2]

---

A version that is more stable for graphics with sharp corners

```
rectOnGraphics[g_Graphics] := DynamicModule[{w = 17, angles, 
   marker = Rasterize@Magnify[Graphics@Rectangle[{-0.01, 0.05}, {0.01, -0.05}], 0.07],
   rg = Rasterize@g, 
   posT = #[[FindShortestTour[#][[-1, ;; -2]]]] &[PixelValuePositions[Binarize@g, 0]]},
  angles = Function[pNr,
     Median[
      ArcCos[#[[1]]/Norm[#]] &[Subtract @@ Reverse@SortBy[#, Last]] & /@ 
       (Thread[{#[[pNr ;; pNr - 1 + w]], Reverse@#[[pNr + 1 + w ;; pNr + 2 w]]}] &[
         ArrayPad[posT, {{w}, {0}}, "Periodic"]])]
     ]~Array~Length[posT];
  Manipulate[
   Pane[rg, FrameMargins -> {{15, 15}, {15, 15}}], 
   {p, 1, Length@posT, 1, TrackingFunction -> (p = #; locator = posT[[#]]; &)}, 
   {{locator, posT[[1]]}, Locator, 
    TrackingFunction -> (p = Nearest[posT -> Automatic, #][[1]]; locator = posT[[p]]; &), 
    Appearance -> Rotate[marker, angles[[p]]]}, 
   TrackedSymbols :> {p}]]

rectOnGraphics[
 Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {-π/2, π/2}], Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}], 
  Circle[{1, 0}, 1, {-π/2, π/2}], Line[{{0, -1}, {1, -1}}]}]]
```

[image: GIF3]

Answer (score 6):

Some of this code is based on the last example of the docs on `GradientOrientationFilter` You can also smooth out the resulting path and reparametrize the interpolation based on the curve length to get a "constant velocity" displacement for the rectangle-

```
l1 = Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}];
cir = Circle[{1, 0}, 1, {-π/2, π/2}];
l2 = Line[{{0, -1}, {1, -1}}];
geom = {l1, cir, l2};
g = Graphics[geom];

g = Graphics[geom];
img = Erosion[g, 1];
orientation = ImageData[GradientOrientationFilter[img, 5]];
orientation = Image@ArcTan[Sin[orientation], -Cos[orientation]];
n = 100;
nearst = Nearest[ImageValuePositions[MorphologicalPerimeter[Binarize[img, {0, .5}]], 1]]
pos = RandomChoice[ImageValuePositions[Binarize@g, 0], n];
curve = FindShortestTour[pos, Method -> "GreedyCycle"];
int = Interpolation /@ Transpose@pos[[Last@curve]];
tint[t_] := Through[int[t]]
o[t_] := ImageValue[orientation, nearst[tint[t], 1]]

Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[tint[t], {t, 1, n}, 
  Epilog -> {Black, Thickness[Large], 
             Line[tint[t] + #*{Cos[o@t], Sin[o@t]} & /@ {-15, 15}]}], 
{t, 2, n-1}]
```

[image]